# JQuery mobile Tree plugin

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can anyone tell me any jQuery Mobile Tree(TreeView, TreeList) plugin?
A good start point to implement it also will be eligible.

Thanks.

Comment: have you take look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305077/tree-structure-with-check-boxes-in-jquery-mobile)?

Answer (score 0):

Many generic jQuery tree plugins will work just as well inside jQuery Mobile; I'd recommend some experimentation.

Another workaround would be to use jQuery mobile's accordion component:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-set.html

With some additional CSS styling, you could make a bunch of nested accordions look like a tree.